# the type of df.describe() result - python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

As shown in the picture, the dtype of 'flags' column is int64. However, when I use flags.describe(), the dtype is float64. I want to know why is it and how I can get a normal result of describe()?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wvdwf.png)

Comment: `describe` returns you some summary statistics for that column, it's not the dtype of the column but the summary statistics for that column

Answer (score 2):

`flags.describe()` is a Series. All Series have a single dtype. Since this Series includes values such as standard deviation and mean which are typically floats, the `flags.describe()` dytpe is a floating-point dtype. So even though `flag.dtype` is `int64`, `flags.describe().dtype` is `float64`.

Comment: Hi~ I want the number like 9.537169e-02 to be usual float format like 0.095, and what should I do to get it?

Comment: Use `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.3f}'.format` to [set the default float format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#available-options).